# Firebase Auth Persistence With React Native on User Creation

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Having an issue with the React Native persistence of Auth. I am using Async Storage as per below. However, the auth state persist only on the 2nd time auth happens not on the first, i.e. when the user signs again after they had created an account. On the first encounter/user creation, auth does not persist.

It should persist on the very first time or at least that's what I want to achieve.

Using

- React Native - 0.73.4
- Firebase SDK Version - 10.8.0
- react-native-async-storage/async-storage - 1.21.0

```
if (getApps().length === 0) {
  app = initializeApp(config);
  auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
  });
} else {
  app = getApp();
  auth = getAuth(app);
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) setUserId(user.uid);
      else setUserId(null);
      console.log("user", user);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
```

I tried last couple of firebase versions and importing from the firebase auth react native entry point, with no luck.

Comment: Can you show us your `import` statement for react-native-async-storage/async-storage?

Comment: The callback in your `useEffect()` does not need to be `async` since it doesn't appear to be calling any functions that themselves are async nor return a Promise.  This won't change the behaviour of the state persistence, but worth pointing out.

Comment: Personally I don't use the `if (getApps().length === 0)` construct anymore.  This is your code...you know when it does and does not go into that code block.  There should never be a situation where you end up with more than one `app`.  And having that conditional makes your code less predictable...like, how do you know that `initializeAuth()` is getting called instead of `getAuth()` ?  Why have both?

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for pointing those items out. I've rectified them. Definitely better for readability and maintenance. They haven't fixed the issue though. Here is how I am importing async storage

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

Comment: P.s I followed the last documented approach as per the firebase github issue. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6050#issuecomment-1119131377

Comment: BTW: have you considered using `react-native-firebase` rather than `firebase`?  I wrote [this article comparing the two](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/expo-react-native-firebase).  Oh -- and use Expo!

Comment: I am definitely considering moving to react-native-firebase. One thing holding me back is migrating all the firestore logic. Would it work / would there be negative implications if I kept firestore logic using firebase and moved the rest to react-native-firebase?

Comment: The API is nearly identical.  There are a few tweaks you might have to make.  Be sure to use the latest version of RNF as it now supports the "modular API" syntax (that came with Firebase v9), though the docs might not have caught up yet.  Check out some of the test cases in the RNF repository and they'll show you that it is nearly identical to Firebase.

Comment: See: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6705

Comment: BTW: it is still possible (I believe...I've seen it done) to get the Firebase Web Client SDK working with Auth persistence.  The info (and code) to get it done has changed a few times over the past few years.  I believe what you have shown above is the latest iteration so "it should work" ?

Comment: Will check these out, thank you. And yes, the web client persistence work just on user creation which is really weird. Might have to look at migration soon if I can't figure this out.

Comment: @GregFenton, any thoughts on doing the persistence manually / without the firebase auth getReactNativePersistence? My thinking is that when auth changes, I do AsyncStorage.setItem. I imagine, that's what getReactNativePersistence does. All I need from the observer is the userId. And signout same thing.

Comment: **Solved** Turns out all the issue was that one of the sign in methods I used was signInWithCustomToken where the user name and email were not attached to the auth user details. In that case, the persistence does not work. Set those details and persistence works.